# Print all printable ASCII characters

Tags: beginner, brainfuck

##### Code:

```
# Range 32-126 (inclusive) is printable 
# We'd store the result of '126-32+1' into cell 1 and start printing
# from 32 until cell 1 becomes 0 and then print again for the zeroth 
# index

+++++>++++++++++[<+++++++++>-]      # 95
>++++++++[<++++>-]<<                # 32
[>.+<-]>.                             
<++++++++++.                        # \n
```

##### Output:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

##### Review Request:

- Is this readable, idiomatic code?
- Is it memory-efficient?
- How can it be written better?

Comment: Readable code seems to be in the eye of the beholder, but well it's [tag:brainfuck] 